# If I re-key a SSL certificate for a 2nd/backup server, does the original still work?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a production server with a wildcard SSL certificate.  I'm in the process of creating a backup/failover server that will host the same domains, and therefore will also need the SSL certificate.

The certificate on the primary server was installed with the private key non-exportable, so I am unable to export the certificate for installation on the failover server.

My question then is - if I re-key the certificate from Go Daddy, does the original certificate installed on the primary server cease to be valid?

As an aside, the original (primary) server is IIS 6, the failover is IIS 7 (once the failover is operational, we'll likely upgrade the primary).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rekeying a certificate revokes the original. See [here](http://help.godaddy.com/article/867) for GoDaddy's support page on rekeying, and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revocation_list) for information on certificate revokation lists.

Comment: Thank you.  I was under the impression that when a key was generated, the CSR process is computer-specific.  If so, how does one install a SSL cert across 2 servers, such as my primary/failover scenario above? (should I post this as another question?)

Comment: @Matt: Yes that should be another question :)

Comment: You can use a certificate for two servers, as long as it is valid for both of them (wildcard)

Answer (score 2):

You should be OK with exporting the certificate from the primary server and importing it to the secondary server. This is what I do with my Exchange servers.

If any one sees a technical or legal issue with this, please let me know.

Comment: Exporting the certificate with the private key works great, but many SSL providers require a server license to be paid for each server the certificate is used on. GoDaddy has an unlimited server license though so exporting is the right answer in this case.

Comment: From the question "with the private key non-exportable" so no exporting is going to happen.